# How do you evaluate this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

let $f(t)= e^{-1/t}$

$f'(t)= f(t)/t^2= \frac{e^{-1/t}}{t^2}$

Then how do I evaluate the right derivative at 0?

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}f'(t) = \lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/t}}{t^2}$$

By L'hostipal's rule, this is

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+} \frac{e^{-1/t}}{2t^3}$$

I have noticed that if I keep applying L'hostipal's rule, the numerator will stay the same where the denominator will just habve a higher degree.
I know the answer is 0 I'm not sure how to justify that.

Then how would I do this?

Comment: Let $u = 1/t$ and change the limit accordingly, the limit should then be clear. Also, $f' = -e^{-1/t}/t^{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitution: set $u=\dfrac1t$, so
$$\lim_{t\to 0_+}\frac{\mathrm e^{-1/t}}{t^2}=\lim_{u\to+\infty}\frac{u^2}{\mathrm e^u}=0\quad\text{(basic limit)}.$$